# PBR and Specular Aliasing

Tags: physically-based, specular

I have been following [LearnOpenGL.com](https://learnopengl.com/)'s tutorials on PBR. Everything makes sense and I wrote up a shader for my physically based renderer.

I noticed that the results look great, however all of my metal objects have such a strong specular on the edges thanks to my Fresnel calculation, and it is producing specular aliasing.

See image:

[image: Illustration of shading aliasing]

I can't seem to figure out why, or how to fix this. I also uploaded a simplified version of my PBR fragment shader. If someone could take a look, I would really appreciate it.

Simplified PBR fragment shader: https://textuploader.com/dv3h1

Here is the tutorial I am following: https://learnopengl.com/PBR/Lighting
It doesn't seem to have any of these specular aliasing issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create an none textured specular-only and fresnel-only image to help visualise were the problem is ?

Comment: This PBR code contains many calculations prone to math errors like division by zero which cause undefined behaviour, i'd check that first and add some margin to prevent this like `max(1e-5, something)`. I actually implemented this tutorial some time ago and did some corrections.

Answer (score 1):

I'll point out that even if you did implement it correctly, at 1 sample per pixel with low roughness materials you'll still see heavy specular aliasing. It's not uncommon to see the firefly pattern on edges on low roughness materials.

For reference see the Infiltrator demo without TAA

> http://advances.realtimerendering.com/s2014/epic/TemporalAA_Compare.mov
>
> http://advances.realtimerendering.com/s2014/index.html#_HIGH-QUALITY_TEMPORAL_SUPERSAMPLING

Comment: You might also check out [LEAN Mapping](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2011/course/TDA361/Advanced%20Computer%20Graphics/LEANpres.pdf).